# PHP Check if word exists between h2 tags

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match, match, h2

I have this SEO script, where i am looking in my **$row['content']** for **$row_meta['keyword']** which is my search focus keyword.

I want to check if an h1, h2, h3 or h4 tags in having my keyword inside. For example if my **$row_meta['keyword'] = "test";** this text should be a match:

```
This is my text
<h2>We just want to test</h2>
but this text containing test is not a match, only between h tags.
```

Is anybody able to help me?

I have something alike, which is testing if i have any img tags containing an alt tag with my keyword in, this is my code for that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($row['content']);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $alt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
    if (preg_match("/\b".$row_meta['keyword']."\b/", $alt)) {
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct (I haven't done php in an age and not sure if this is the correct parser) but I think you can do the following

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($row['content']);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
    $text = $h2->nodeValue;
    if (preg_match("/\b".$row_meta['keyword']."\b/", $text)) {
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, no matches :-(

Comment: does `plaintext` return anything - it may be the wrong  parser

Comment: print_r($text); returns nothing

Comment: try using `nodeValue`.  The documentation isn't great for the parser

Comment: If you're not sure about the potential content of `$row_meta['keyword']` then you might want to escape any characters in it that would otherwise break the regex, eg `/ * + [` etc using a nested preg_replace.

Comment: @GavinJackson thank you for your adwice, and under other circumstances i would follow your adwice. But i know my keyword wont be holding any characters except for letters and spaces. Its build to hold one or two words, entered by an administrator of the page.